# What is the best way to trim a dictionary after sorting?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I want to reduce the number of items in a dictionary. So I need to trim dictionary after sorting by value. My question is how?

So I to trim this dict so only the top TWO entries are retained—

```
base_dic={'Cs':0,5, 'Cp':0.3, 'Os':0.6, 'Op': 0.9}
```

I've tried—

```
dict(sorted(base.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:2])
```

But is this the best way? And to display or compare the values in dictionary, is there smart way to ordering by value? Note that it is not just sorting of values, it is sorting of dictionary using values.

I want to have only a few elements with maximum values. That is, from

```
base={'Cs':0,5, 'Cp':0.3, 'Os':0.6, 'Op': 0.9, .... 100 elements}
```

to such as

```
base={'Op': 0.99, 'Nid': 0.97}
```

Effectively retaining only the top TWO elements and discarding the rest.

Comment: What is your expected out?

Comment: What does "trim" mean in the context of a dictionary?

Comment: in the dictionary it might have dict={ 'a': 0.7, 'b': 0.3 ...} about 30 elements, So I want to sort and leave a few elements.

Comment: So you want the top two entries from the dictionary?

Comment: Which few elements, and how do you decide whether to keep it or remove it? You mention that sorting just by values doesn't meet your requirements.

Comment: "sort and leave a few": meaning: take e.g. only the first 5?

Comment: I've edited your question into shape, I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my english. I need just a few values with keys. a few 2 ~ 5 among over 100 items.

Comment: @AChampion: The value itself is the contribution so I want to have some keys with highest values.

Comment: @JoonhoPark how does what you have tried not meet your requirements?

Comment: I tried to find a solution by studying this quickly and it may work but I wanted to get more from experts if there is another way.

Comment: @JoonhoPark why not, I don't think you should be penalised for your grammar here. That's why I made it a point to fix your question for clarity. By the way, please consider taking a look at the answers below.

Comment: Both answers are good. The top one is more heuristic while the bottom one is shorter. If I understand heapq, I will choose the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you suggest is certainly pythonic.  The only issue I can see is that you need just the two biggest elements, but still have to sort all tuples in the dict: this could be done more efficiently with [`heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest)

```
values = dict(heapq.nlargest(2, mydict.items(), lambda i: i[1]))
```

Comment: This looks shorter using module of heapq

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is more or less the most obvious way to do it. You could aim to get rid of the lambda for a cleaner solution using `base_dic.get`.

```
keys = sorted(base_dic.keys(), key=base_dic.get, reverse=True)[:2]
trim_dict = {k : base_dic[k] for k in keys}
```